# How to set a JS object property name dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner in javascript and I'm having trouble creating this object below dynamically. All names must be extracted from a text entry and dynamically inserted into the object.

```
var object = {
        "users" : {
            // Names dynamically inserted
            "Isaac" : {
                "name" : "Isaac de Araujo Meneses",
                "age" : "25" 
            }
            "John"{
                "name" : "John Miller",
                "age" : "32" 
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code that I wrote:

```
var name = form.name.value;

    var object = {
        "users" : {
            // Names dynamically inserted
            name : {
                "name" : name,
                "age" : "25" 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base code:

```
var object = {
  users: {
    "John": {
      name: "John Smith",
      age: "140" // Why not?
    }
  }
}
```

To add a new user:

```
var name = form.name.value;
var age = form.age.value;
object.users[name] = {
  name: name,
  age: age
}
```

Comment: alert(object.users[john].age);

How to acess this?

Comment: `object.users["john"].age` you need to have the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the object key dynamically like that:

```
var name = form.name.value; //suppose you get 'Isaac' here

var object = {
    "users" : {
    }
}

object.users[name] = {
    name: name,
    age: 25 
}

console.log(object);
/*
{
    "users": {
            "Isaac": {
                "name": "Isaac",
                "age": 25
            }
        }
    }
*/
```